# Passing params from checkbox to same page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have multiple checkbox on index. when I check the checkbox, each should have a different value.

I want get a value of each checkbox and pass the value with params... and when the page reload, I want see all the params of checkbox who was checked on index

ex
.
Checkbox_1 = checked

Checkbox_2 = checked

Checkbox_3 = unchecked

Checkbox_4 = checked

Checkbox_5 = unchecked

On reload the variable

`teste: <%= @value %>`

on view should show:

teste: [1,2,4]

who I should make the checkbox on view and on controller

Answer (score 1):

position will loop the value based your loop (for active records data with each / map command), checkbox_array will returned the result as you requested above

```
   <% position = 1 %>
    <% your looping command here  %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'checkbox_array[]', position,false %>
        <% position = position + 1 %>
    <% end %>
```

inside your index.html.erb

```
link_to "your model", model_path(:my_values => checkbox_array)
```

I tried to follow your request, my idea is from your index page, you passed the content of checkbox_array through link_to parameters, and above is the example

Comment: Here the `false` argument should be `true` or `false` depending on if you want it checked or not.

Comment: I want to know how i pass the values of checkbox to params[:checkbox_array] on controller and show on view <%= @value %>

Comment: as rails convention, both index and show are for showing data (http: get), usually for your case I put list of checkbox inside controller new, and then save the params[:checkbox_array] result inside controller create, to show the result is also based from model/table structure that save the values

Comment: The value of the check box does not need to be saved. When a person accesses the page, a modal appears with the check box, when the person selects the check box and clicks the button. Example: "exit", the modal will be hidden and the value of the check box will be displayed on the screen